# UML to SQL(generic) MagicDraw

Tags: magic-draw

i need to convert ER model to SQL diagram with MagicDraw, so i use this http://puu.sh/rRy3F.png but there isnt option:UML to SQL(generic), which is supposed to be there, how do  i add that?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of missing Cameo Data Modeler plugin installed. You have to go to Help->Resource/Plugin Manager and install it manually.

Don't forget to restart your MagicDraw after installation will be finished.

Information from:
https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD184/Available+Transformations